# How to make a column hold the length of an other column in mysql?

Tags: mysql, triggers, string-length

I have a simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE Tabale.new_table (
  index INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  col1 VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  length_of_col1 INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (index),
  UNIQUE INDEX index_UNIQUE (index ASC) VISIBLE);
```

I would like for index length_of_col1 to automatically hold the length of the col1

```
ALTER TABLE Table.new_table 
CHANGE COLUMN length_of_col1 length_of_col1 INT NULL DEFAULT LENGTH(new_table.col1) ;
```

but instead I got

```
Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
Executing:
ALTER TABLE Table.new_table 
CHANGE COLUMN length_of_col1 length_of_col1 INT NULL DEFAULT LENGTH(new_table.col1) ;

ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near LENGTH(new_table.col1) at line 2
SQL Statement:
ALTER TABLE Table.new_table 
CHANGE COLUMN length_of_col1 length_of_col1 INT NULL DEFAULT LENGTH(new_table.col1)
```

Do I have to define a trigger  instead?

Comment: You do need to use a couple of triggers if you would like the derived column which is based on the values of another column to AUTOMATICALLY reflect the changes. One for INSERT to get the initial value and another one for UPDATE .

Comment: I don't understand As you have set the length of col1 VARCHAR(45) So why are you not setting the default length for length_of_col1 - 2 or 3 as it will always store a 2 digit value

Comment: @Yogendra Those Length parameters are generated by work bench and are not important. I am asking for the procedure that would automatically set the length for the column

Answer (score -1):

I think issue with your ALTER TABLE statement is that you are trying to reference the 'new_table' alias within the DEFAULT clause, which is not allowed. You need to remove the 'new_table' alias and use just 'col1' in the DEFAULT clause.
Try this

```
ALTER TABLE Table.new_table 
CHANGE COLUMN length_of_col1 length_of_col1 INT NULL DEFAULT LENGTH(col1);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).